# Lawn mower Dies once started

Tags: engine

I have a lawn mower that dies about 5 seconds after It's started, I've removed the carb and cleaned the ports, I've also tested the coil and spark plug with a spark plug tester in between the coil and the spark plug, There was a spark

So I checked the oil and filter, The filter was fine but the oil was filled way past the mark so I decided to remove the spark plug, turns out it was black, so I changed it and it ran fine for about 30 minutes, then it died again.

I removed the spark plug again and it has a light brown oily residue on the edges of the plug, but not on the electrode, any Idea's why it keeps dying ? could the piston rings be shot from someone over filling the oil

Comment: Not sure what to say here. You've exercised (to us) the idea that you've done this before. If that is the case, then how is "someone overfilling it?" What you didn't say, and should correct if you didn't correct it, is DRAIN the oil, and keep it at the right level. Fire clean the plug. Also, ensure the tank has NO deposits in it, ensure the fuel line is clear, filter if it has one (for FUEL) is clear and that the gas cap breathes properly. And in the future, do the easy things first. (cleaning a carb can be tricky, and if goofed, a nightmare to sort out if inexperienced)

Comment: Has “someone” used a 2-stroke mix for the fuel? After removing the ports on the carb, did you reset them correctly?

Comment: @SolarMike I drained the fuel and reset them correctly, at noybman the oil was drained and refilled to the correct level, the fuel line is way short and clear of any obstructions and the  push mower filter has been cleaned, as I said I just replaced the spark plug and set it to .30 instead of cleaning it up... it just drives me wild that it would only run for 5 seconds, then after replacing the spark plug, it only ran for 30 minutes

Comment: Is the plug wet (with fuel) after it runs? It could be that the check valve in the carb is faulty, flooding the cylinder.

Comment: Its generally simply, air, fuel, or spark. What you describe leads us to believe spark is "ok" but you can clean all the connections up. With air, you'd suffocate fast enough that it wouldn'b be running for 30m. So it sounds like fuel first, spark second. You mentioned a dirty plug that was oily. So sure the piston rings might be tired but I usually like to ensure fuel is good - you ran for 30m, it probably is. Is this fresh gas? Presume since you drained it that it is, but if its from what was laying around, it could be bad gas still.

Comment: Ok, so after double checking everything I've done... I rechecked and recleaned the carb, and everything is set and working, I've also fire cleaned the spark plug and tested it, theres no ohms to the case from the electrode, but there is .5-.6 resistance on the electrode, The coil pack reads 6 ohms, and from the kill wire to the plug there's no ohms... The mower started for 3 seconds when I set the plug to 25, it didnt start at .30 or .20... ugh, could it be that the ohms on the coil pack itself are too weak ?

Comment: A coil pack should read near 0 ohms in general (6 ohms is good), meaning, you would not expect a coil pack to read megaohms (open is bad). 0 would be bad too. You cant really tell if a coil is still good simply on its resistance, the inductance is whats important. They are cheap, if it looks rusted, replace it. Make sure it is tight and everything is clean (including the wires and the spade connectors). You should have the spark gap set to the engine MFR setting. You;re not really supposed to tweak them. Yes, weak spark would be a problem and can be your problem too.